I am getting this error when building the react native expo app, "Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error."
All the steps for build are successful, gives the error from "Run gradlew"(https://i.sstatic.net/DcdxEC4E.png)
This is the Run gradlew logs
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/frontend/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30
%.
40%.
50%.
60%
70
%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Support for Java 18
Support for building with Groovy 4
Much more responsive continuous builds
Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build


Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
Configure project :expo-application
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-constants
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-file-system
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-font
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-image-loader
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-image-picker
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-keep-awake
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo-modules-core
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Checking the license for package CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package CMake 3.22.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)".
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" ready.
Installing CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" complete.
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" finished.
Configure project :expo-splash-screen
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
Configure project :expo
Using expo modules


[32mexpo-application[0m (5.1.1)
[32mexpo-constants[0m (14.2.1)
[32mexpo-file-system[0m (15.2.2)
[32mexpo-font[0m (11.1.1)
[32mexpo-image-loader[0m (4.1.1)
[32mexpo-image-picker[0m (14.1.1)
[32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (12.0.1)
[32mexpo-modules-core[0m (1.2.7)
[32mexpo-splash-screen[0m (0.18.2)
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/frontend/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/build.gradle' line: 25
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-picker'.


Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2m 28s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

This is my package.json file
{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
"expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"i18next": "^23.4.6",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
"lodash.filter": "^4.6.0",
"nativewind": "^2.0.11",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^13.2.2",
"react-native": "0.71.14",
"react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.1",
"react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.3.3",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
"react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
"react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
"react-native-picker": "^4.3.7",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
"react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
"react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
"react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
"react-native-screens-swiper": "^1.2.6",
"react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.9",
"react-native-tts": "^4.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
"react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
"react-native-youtube": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}
How to resolve this issue, i am trying to create a apk file. using "eas build -p android"
